# Why can't I use a defined function inside another defined function,when creating an js object?

Tags: javascript

The code goes like this

```
var ob = {
    a: function() {
        b()
    },
    b: function() {
        console.log("hi")
    }
};
```

As you can see, you can't do

```
ob.a() //returns error
```

Can someone explain the reason in depth?

Comment: Add this keyword to function call: var ob = {a:function(){this.b()},b:function(){console.log("hi")}};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Becuase `b` does not exist in the current scope (which is the global one in this case).

This works, however:

```
var ob = {
  a: function () {
    this.b()
  },
  b: function () {
    console.log('hi')
  }
};
```

because `this` refers to the `ob` object.

Answer (score 1):

The `b` is a property of the object called `ob`. That being said, if you use

```
ob.b
```

instead of `b` you will solve your problem.

```
var ob = {
    a:function(){ 
        ob.b() 
    },
    b:function(){
        console.log("hi")
    }
};
```

Another way to do achieve this is to use the `this` operator.

```
var ob = {
    a:function(){ 
        this.b() 
    },
    b:function(){
        console.log("hi")
    }
};
```

The `this` holds a reference to the object you define. Hence using it you can access is properties. It is a better way that the first way, because if you decide later to alter the name of `ob` to `obj`, you will not have change it in two places.

Comment: @jeff Thank you :). I was about to add it, when you hit your comment !

Answer (score 1):

There is no function `b` defined anywhere, it's a property of object `ob`, so you can refer it as `this.b` from inside `a`:

```
var ob = {
    a: function () {
        this.b();
    },
    b: function () {
        console.log("hi");
    }
};

ob.a();
```

You could also access `b` as `ob.b()`.